# Understanding the $l!$ in the probability of $l$ events from a set of $N$ to happen at the same timestep out of $n$ total

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I know this is probably a simple question but honestly I've been struggling with it for a couple of days already.

I have $N$ independent events. Each of them can occur with equal probabilities in any of $n$ timesteps. I want to compute the probability of $l$ events to happen together. I find two expressions and I am not sure which one is the right one.

FIRST EXPRESSION:
The probability of the event $i$ happening in the time $t_j$ is $\frac{1}{n}$
The probability of the event $h$ happening in the time $t_j$ is $\frac{1}{n}$
...
The the proba of any event happening at time $t_j$ is $\sum^{N} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{N}{n}$

Then, the probability of second event happening at $t_j$ would be  $\sum^{N-1} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{N-1}{n}$, because there are only $N-1$ events available. And then,
the probability of two events happening at time $t_{j}$ is $ \frac{N}{n} \frac{N-1}{n}$

Following the same reasoning for $l$ events occurring together at time $t_{j}$:
the probability of $l$ events occurring at time $t_j$: $ \frac{N}{n} \frac{N-1}{n} \dots \frac{N-(l-1)}{n}$

But I want to know the probability of events occurring at the same time, not only at $t_j$ but at any any $t_i$ in $n$,
the probability of $l$ events cooccurring at any time is: $ \frac{N}{n} \frac{N-1}{n} \dots \frac{N-(l-1)}{n} \times n = \frac{N!}{(N-l)! n^{l-1}}$

SECOND EXRPESSION:
The probability of the event $i$ happening in the time $t_j$ is $\frac{1}{n}$
The probability of the event $h$ happening in the time $t_j$ is $\frac{1}{n}$
...
Then, the probability of $l$ specific events to happen at time $t_{j}$ is $\frac{1}{n} \dots \frac{1}{n}$ ($l$ times).

And since this could be for any of the $n$ timesteps,
the probability of this $l$ events to happen at any time is $\frac{1}{n^l}n = \frac{1}{n^{l-1}}$

But here we considered only one specific set of $l$ events, to have all the possible ways to take $l$ from $N$ where the order is meaningless, we can compute the combination $\binom{N}{l}$.

And we get: $\frac{1}{n^{l-1}} \binom{N}{l} $

QUESTION:

We see that both expressions actually are "similar". They differ in a $\frac{1}{l!}$ factor. I guess this is usually a matter of considering the events undistinguishable or not... but honestly, not sure which one is correct in this case.

Another not non-important issue, but that I can only solve after solving problem 1 is about normalization but I will ask that when i solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vision of the sum of probability is a bit distorted. Both the reasonings are not correct since you add possibilities of events that are not incompatible.

Here some examples:

- If you toss a normal dice, the probability of getting 1 is $1/6$, and also the prob of getting 2 is $1/6$. The probability to get 1 or 2 is the sum of prob $2/6$, since the events are incompatible: you can't get at the same time 1 and 2.
- If now you toss 2 dices, the probability to get 1 on the first dice is still $1/6$, and the probability to get a 2 on the second dice is also $1/6$. What is the probability of getting a 1 on the first dice or a 2 on the second dice? the possible couples of results are $36 = 6^2$, and the farovable results are $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)$ that are 11. the resulting probability is this $11/36$ that is different from the sum $2/6$. This happens because the two events can happen simultaneously when the result is $(1,2)$

In both your reasonings the probability that you're summing belongs to events that may happen at the same time!

- In the first case, litterally the events happen at the same time (pun not intended). The real probability of any event happening at time $t_j$ is
  $$1 - \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^N$$
  that is the opposite of the probability that no events take place at time $t_j$
- In the second case, if you take two distinct sets of $l$ events, they may happen at time $t_j$ together. In this case it is more difficult to point out the correct answer, since the events are not even independent.

The real answer is quite complicated and I don't know if there's a close form, sorry.

Comment: Sounds good.I understand `(n-1)/n` is the proba of one event happening at any other than than tj, and for N events will be that to the power of `N`. I am still tempted though, to multiply this by `n` to make it the probability of any event happening at any time (which should be identically 1). But that does not work.

Comment: "In the second case, if you take two distinct sets of l events, they may happen at time tj together. In this case it is more difficult to point out the correct answer, since the events are not even independent." You meant that they are not independent or that they are overlapping?

Comment: @myradio they are not independent precisely because they're overlapping